# Is $a_n = \frac{c^n}{n!}$ decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n = \frac{c^n}{n!}$, where $c \ge 0$. A teacher at my class said the sequence {$a_n$} is monotonic, so I suppose it is decreasing, but I am unable to prove it. For any $2 < c < \infty$, {$a_n$} first increases until reaching a point $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \ge N$, then {$a_n$} starts to decrease. For example, {$\frac{3^n}{n!}$} $=$ {$3, 4.5, 4.5, 3.375, 2.025, ...$} so it decreases from $n \ge 4$ onwards. If a sequence does not decrease from the very beginning, it is not a decreasing sequence. It seems to me the only choice of $c$ that makes the sequence truly decreasing is $0 \le c \le 2$. So is {$a_n$} really decreasing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is not monotonic but eventually monotonic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sequence is *eventually* decreasing, which means that, for some $p\in\Bbb N$, the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geqslant p}$ is decreasing. That follows from the fact that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$ if $n$ is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

We have $ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \frac{c}{n+1}.$

Hence

$$a_{n+1 } \ge a_n \iff n \ge c-1.$$